Can a 2-sphere be squashed flat?
Does there exist a function $f:\Bbb{S}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^2$ which preserves the length of every rectifiable curve? That is, can a sphere be crushed flat without tears? Of course, this is a Nash-Kuiper type problem, so my question is really whether such a result is already known. If so, I would love to have a reference.
Thanks in advance!

Will you solve this small ambiguity about "length": "The map $f$ preserves the length of rectifiable curves" : does this mean : for every (continuous) rectifiable $u:[0,1]\to \mathbb S^2$ the length of $f\circ u$ is equal to the lenght of $u$ (length=total variation). Or does it mean: "for every $\Gamma\subset \mathbb S^2$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ the length of $\Gamma$  is equal to the length of $f(\Gamma)$ (length=$\mathcal H^1$) ?

It is defined as the supremum of lengths of inscribed polygons. For example, the simplest non-trivial length preserving map from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to itself is given by folding along the $x$-axis. This preserves length as given by the first definition, but not as given by the second. Indeed, it suffices to consider vertical curves which cross the $x$-axis.

Don't forget to mention what your polygons are inscribed in.

There does exist such a map, if it is not required to be $C^1$. (The nice answer of Guido De Philippis gives a proof that such a map cannot be $C^1$.). See "Lecture 4" ("Gromov's Rumpling Theorem") in the lecture notes of Petrunin-Yashinski here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.6606
A more general result is in section 2.4.11 of Gromov's book Partial Differential Relations.

Nice reference, thank you! i will edit the answer accordingly!

That's an astonishing theorem. I'm curious if there's an existing visualization of this type of map, along the lines of what the Hevea Project did for Nash embeddings.

According to the reference posted below there is indeed such a map. However, such a map would not exists if one assumes some (minor) smoothness. Note that this is somehow in contrast with the Nash Kupier theorem where the map is indeed $C^1$.
In particular, I will prove  below that  there is no  $C^1$ map $f: U\subset \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such  that
\begin{equation*}
(df)^Tdf=g \, ,
\label{e1}
\end{equation*}
where $g$ is any smooth metric with non zero Gauss curvature.
I believe that the proof below is well known, but I do not have a reference.
First, note that non existence of a smooth map satisfying the above equation  follows from  the  invariance of the Gauss curvature under isometry.
To prove the  claim one  thus only  has to show that any $C^1$ map satisfying the above equation is indeed smooth. For, note that it  implies that
\begin{equation*}
(df)^{-1}=g^{-1}(df)^T \qquad \det df=\sqrt{\det g}
\end{equation*}
and thus
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_2 f^2 &-\partial_1 f^2 
\\
-\partial_2 f^1 & \partial_1 f^1 
\end{pmatrix}
= \det df \, (df)^{-T}
=\sqrt{\det g}  \,df \, g^{-T}. 
\end{equation*}
The distributional rowise divergence of the first matrix is zero, hence $f$ is satisfying the elliptic equation
$$
\mathrm{div} (\sqrt{\det g}  \,Df \, g^{-T})=0.
$$
Classical elliptic regularity theory implies that $f$ is smooth and thus that the classical rigidity can be applied.
To put the proof in perspective,  note that this is a "non constant coefficient"  version of the classical argument of Reshetnyak about the rigidity of the inclusion $df \in SO(n)$, as presented,  for instance, in  these  notes.
As a concluding remark, observe  that the rigidity comes from the equality between the dimensions of the target and source domain. The Nash-Kupier needs indeed  some co-dimension  to add winkles to a short  embedding in order to make it isometric.

That's an interesting complement. Thankyou very much!

By the way, is it true that if a Finsler sphere was not already conformally (Alexandrov) flat, then it cannot be $C^1$ squashed?

I think this should probably follow also from the remarks in the lecture notes linked in the other answer. Specifically, they provide an argument that a length-preserving function cannot be injective on any open set, which for $C^1$ functions implies that the differential is singular everywhere, which should contradict preserving lengths (but my differential geometry is a bit rusty, so don't quote me on that).
